# Discord JDA wont import JDABuilder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, discord, discord-jda

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'

}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
    implementation("net.dv8tion:JDA:5.0.0-alpha.8")


}



test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

bot.java

```
package Main;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
        ;


public class testbotgradle {
    public static void  main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDABuilder jda = new JDABuilder.createDefault("my tocen");
        jda.setActivity(Ativity.playing("test"));
                jda.setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        jda.build();
    }
 }
```

throws

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bot

Also seams like Java cant import the JDA package but I have no idea why. I have installed the dependencies. They are in the same project. Im using IntellijIDEA

Comment: Your Java class file must have the same name as the class: `testbotgradle`. Also, the naming guidelines recommend using upper case for first class name letter ([CamelCase notation](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)).

Comment: You need to remove the `new` before `JDABuilder`. You are calling a static method, not a constructor.